# Javascript: How to embed and truncate Tumblr blog posts

Tags: javascript, json, blogs, tumblr, posts

Using Tumblr's JSON API, I have embedded blog posts into another website. However, the blog posts are long and the idea is just to show a snippet of the most recent posts, with a link if they wish to read more.

**You can see the example here**: http://jsbin.com/ibede5/9 - edit at your will.

**For each post, I need to truncate and add an ellipsis ('...').** The only problem is that doing so through the JSON API is almost impossible since there are so many hidden code characters (meaning my working first post example extracts the characters using `.substring(35868, 36070)` which is just insane). It doesn't work on the second post either.

So ideally I need to truncate only once the JSON API code has been transferred into standard HTML.

Also, the only way I've found to include images from the posts is by appending the post a second time and using `'display: none;` to hide the text, leaving just the image. Surely there's a better way?

Any ideas? Should I even bother using their JSON API for this?

Many thanks.

Comment: can't you just do something like `.left(whatever.indexOf('</p>')) + '...'` ? that will find the end of the first paragraph and ellipse it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the post['regular-body'] to an element's innerHTML property to be able to retrieve the body as text, then do a substring on that:

```
elem = $('<div></div>');
elem.html(p['regular-body']);
text = elem.text();
body = text.substring(0, 128);
```

Now that `elem` contains all of the HTML from `p['regular-body']`, you can search within it. To find `<img>` elements, do:

```
var images = $(elem).find('img');
```

Comment: Great! It worked a charm. Thanks, Samplebias. Any recommendations for pulling images out from 'regular-body'? Seems using the `display: none;` style on the text keeps the height of, so there is a huge (variable-sized) gap in place of the invisible text.

Comment: Glad it helped. Once you've created `elem` and set the `html()`, you can apply jQuery methods to that element. I'll update the answer to illustrate.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much. Still very much a javascript and jQuery amateur, so this saved me a lot of time and pain.